# View the surface of Mars via Hubble

Tags: mars, curiosity, hubble

Has the surface of Mars been observed by the mirror of Hubble ? 
For example, it could be a good idea for humans to be able to see the lovely Curiosity Rover via Hubble from above.

Comment: Hi Merlin. I feel like this is a very googlable question. Learn to use google. "Hubble image Mars" immediately gives results. Furthermore you cannot see rovers via Hubble. Its resolution power is not sufficient. You need to be a satellite in orbit around Mars to do what you propose.

Comment: " The Apollo descent stages left on the lunar surface are too small to be seen by Hubble, which can see objects as small as 60-75 yards, about three-quarters the length of a soccer field. The left-behind descent stages are only about the size of a small truck."  --  Curiosity is smaller than the LM descent stage, and much further away

Comment: Greetings to you and thank you for your answer. Yes, Google is definitely a good tool for asking questions, but I can never find a person like you who is knowledgeable and kind and knowledgeable on Google, and I have the exact answer. 

Comment: It would be a waste to target Mars (or the Moon) with Hubble, since very good surface maps of each have been obtained from the various orbiters launched over the decades. The Viking orbiters for example arrived in the '70s and produced much better Mars imagery than anything Hubble could do.  There are currently six operational Mars orbiters.

Comment: @antlersoft: Hubble is occasionally used for Mars observations. It has instruments that the orbiters don't and can view an entire hemisphere at once with them, rather than a closeup of a patch of ground: https://hubblesite.org/images/gallery/62-mars

Comment: @JCRM More interestingly, I was unaware of the accuracy of Hubble's operation, and now I have noticed the magnification of the telescope and the size of the rover on the rover. that was perfect

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Perhaps turn that into a short answer? IMO, this is a good question, and yours is a good answer. I learned something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hubble is occasionally used for Mars observations. It has instruments that the orbiters don't and can view an entire hemisphere at once with them, rather than a closeup of a patch of ground: https://hubblesite.org/images/gallery/62-mars